# How to find the threshold in this example?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance

A client implemented the promotion on July. If we simply evaluate the action, we could compare with June sales of the client.

But if the client is belongs to category Y and we can observe category Y performance on both July and June, the performance evaluation would be more trustful.

For example, if the category Y's growth rate is 5% from June to July and the client's one is 10%, the action provided the positive impact for the client sales.

However, if the client's sales has already composed of 80% of category Y's sales, this comparison would be not trustful since the client contributes category Y's sales a lot.

Is there any statistic method to identify the threshold of this contribution %?
e.g. the client's sales is more than 50% of the category Y's sales, we should not use this comparison, if it is less than 50% would be ok. etc..

Comment: The term "ad hoc" comes immediately to mind.  Otherwise, could you more specifically explain what you mean by "identify the threshold"?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What I mean by "identify the threshold" is (A) if the client sales is 50K and category Y sales is 100K, it means the client' impact of category Y is 50%. (B) if the client sales is 1K and category Y sales is 100K, it means the client' impact of category Y is 1%.  If we want to compare the client performance, we cannot compare the client performance with the case (A) since the client dominated the category Y sales. But how we can define the client dominates category Y sales?

Comment: I just say 50% in this case, but it would be more statistically for us to tell XX% would be dominated or not?